# Counter example to the parallelogram identity

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $Z$ be the linear space of all sequences of complex numbers $z=(z_1 , z_2, z_3,..)$ such that $$ \sum^\infty _ {j=1} |z_{2j}|< \infty$$ and $$  \sum^\infty _{k=0} |z_{2k+1}|^2 < \infty$$

It can be shown that the formula $$||z||=\sum^\infty_{j=1} |z_{2j}| + \bigg( \sum^\infty _{k=0} |z_{2k+1} |^2 \bigg)^\frac{1}{2}$$
where $z =\{z_n\} \in Z$

defines a norm on $Z$.

I am trying to give a counter example for the Paralleogram law $$||u+v||^2 + ||u-v||^2 =2(||u||^2 + ||v||^2)$$

This is the counter example I have. 
Let $z=(1,0,0,..)$ and $w=(0,1,0,0,..)$

Then we can see $$||z+w||^2 + ||z-w||^2=8 \neq4=2(||z||^2 + ||w||^2)$$

> How do you get the values $8$ and $4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $\lVert z \rVert = \lVert w \rVert = 1$, so $2\left( {\lVert z \rVert}^2+{\lVert w \rVert}^2\right)=2(1+1)=4$.

On the other hand, we have that $z+w = (1,1,0,0,\dots)$ and $z-w = (1,-1,0,0,\dots)$, so

$$\lVert z+w \rVert = |1| + \left(1^2\right)^{\frac12} = 2$$
$$\lVert z-w \rVert = |-1| + \left(1^2\right)^{\frac12} = 2$$

Therefore, ${\lVert z+w \rVert}^2 + {\lVert z-w \rVert}^2=4+4=8$.

Comment: How did you get $||z||=||w||=1$?

Comment: Just apply the norm formula.$$\lVert z \rVert = {\left(|1|^2\right)}^{\frac12}=1$$
$$\lVert w \rVert = |1|=1$$